# Powershell Running Command Line as Admin User

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, automation

So I have automation that logs into a Windows Server 2019 machine as one user, but then needs to run a command (*Invoke-AdminCommand* is application specific, not a built-in Windows cmdlet) as an admin user (and I do not want to add the logged in user as an Admin).  I've followed answers from here (if you think this is a duplicate question) and none have worked.  In the script I do a "whoami" to be sure the session is the correct user, and it is.  But the command returns an application specific error stating the user does not have the correct permissions.  If I RDP into the same machine as the admin user and run the same command through a Powershell CLI - it works fine.

```
$username = "domain\adminUser"
$password = "**********" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
$s = New-PSSession -credential $cred
$sc = {
    whoami
    Invoke-AdminCommand -Register -Verbose
}
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock $sc
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Comment: Even though you're running the command as `adminuser`, the session is not elevated.

Comment: This might help you https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html

Comment: If you are asking if you can elevate a command without provoking a UAC prompt, then the answer is no (and this is by design).

Comment: The user does not need to be elevated. The third party app has the User as a Admin for the application, not Windows Admin group but third party Admin Group

Comment: I guess I don't understand your use case then. Why not just run the command while the needed user is logged on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be hitting the double-hop problem. You are remoting to another server to run another command which itself requires authentication. If you can't lean on **CredSSP** (security risk) or proper account delegation (potentially high overhead in effort to maintain delegations at volume but this is the correct way to go about it).

**Note:** Basic auth will also work around this issue but I highly highly highly do not recommend using basic auth without at least setting up WinRM over SSL and removing non-HTTPS WinRM listeners.

Whether you are using Kerberos (without proper delegation or **CredSSP**) or NTLM (at all as NTLM cannot forward tokens) as the authentication scheme you can work around this by passing the credential information into `Invoke-Command` and building the credential in that script block, and using `Start-Process` to start it as a different user. Note that if you needed to elevate for **UAC**, the code would be different and this code will only work when you *don't* need **UAC** elevation:

```
# We will create the SecureString inside the Invoke-Command block
$password = "********"

# Use of a Dictionary instead of positional arguments and `param` in the block
# is a little trick you can use here.
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ArgumentList @{ Username = $username; Password = $password } {
  $cred =
    [PSCredential]::new($args.Username, ( $args.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ))

  # Placeholder for next part
}
```

So this is the boilerplate for what you want. You send the credentials to the remote server and build it there. How you execute this at `# Placeholder for next part` will depend on what exactly you are running:

- **External Command (executable)**

  - Use `Start-Process` to run the program as the other user

  ```
  Start-Process -Wait -Credential $cred program.exe -ArgumentList "arguments to the program here"
  ```
- **Any cmdlet which accepts a `-Credential` parameter or any command which accepts username and password arguments**

  - Pass the credential argument directly to the cmdlet/function, or pass `$args.Username` and `$args.Password` to an external command which has username/password parameters directly. The below however exemplifies using this with a cmdlet and the `-Credential` parameter.

  ```
  # Note that some cmdlets don't take a credential for whatever reason
  # and may have -Username and -Password arguments instead.
  Invoke-AdminCommand -Credential $cred -Register -Verbose
  ```
- **Any Function or Cmdlet which does not accept a `-Credential` parameter or username/password arguments**

  - This is similar to the first example, but this example specifically targets running a bit of PowerShell code as another user for the code you want.

  ```
  # This can be invoked without splatting but am using splatting for readability
  $spArgs = @{
    Credential = $cred
    FilePath = 'powershell.exe' # You can use `pwsh.exe` for PS Core if necessary
    ArgumentList = "-Command ""exampleProgram.exe -username $($args.Username) -password $($args.Password)"""
    Wait = $true
    NoNewWindow = $true
  }
  Start-Process powershell.exe
  ```

Comment: The command is running on the same machine if that matters

Comment: Then why are you using Invoke-Command with a PS session? Those are for running things remotely. I'll update this answer tomorrow (on mobile now) but you should be able to use one of the Start-Process examples from my answer, no need for a PS Session or Invoke-Command.

Comment: Tried Start-Process (perhaps incorrectly) and had no luck, so then moved to Invoke-Command with a Session as the user I needed.